# How can i access my Objects in a vaadin tree?

Tags: java, tree, vaadin

I`ve added my own objects into a vaadin tree like this:

```
Item item = container.addItem(planet); //where planet is from class Planet
```

If I get it right, only the string taken from planet.toString() will be added to my tree.

Now I need to access several methods/attributes of my object (e.g. getMoons() or getPlanetID()). How can I access my object by selecting this planet in my tree (via getValue() in my valueChanged-event) ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
Planet myPlanet = (Planet) myTree.getValue();
myPlanet.getMoons();
```

Since the `itemId` is an instance of Planet, you can safely cast the `getValue()` result into such.

If you need the container in some other context, check [BeanItemContainer](https://vaadin.com/api/com/vaadin/data/util/BeanItemContainer.html) out.